# Millions of Google Map Marker using MarkerClusterer, JSON/AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, google-maps

I am developing large geo location web site. There are over 2.5 million places to show on Google Map with markers and info window (when marker clicked).

I am using MarkerClusterer to narrow down the load of individual marker.

But, I am afraid if so much data in browser (JSON etc) would really kill the page.

Any suggestions to load on demand JSON by identifying the map bounds when panning is changed.

Any recommendations to resource also appreciated.

Comment: "Any suggestions to load on demand JSON by identifying the map bounds when panning is changed." --- yes, load on demand when map bounds are changed (CO)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cluster](http://www.acme.com/javascript/#Clusterer) I think it may do what you want:

- Only the markers currently visible actually get created.
- If too many markers would be visible, then they are grouped together into cluster
  markers

Comment: I think Cluster only works for Google Maps v2, which is being deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a quadkey. A quadkey is perfect to reduce the dimension complexity and build clusters of the point of interest. There are many different methods like z curve, hilbert curve, peano curve. To further limit the constraints you can attach the cluster thing to the bounding box and the zoom level of the google maps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of marker Clusterer that works for v3 of the google maps api, but that isn't the issue here. The issue is that you'd still be handling the underlying data in the browser with JS (2.5 million places retrieved thru JSON/AJAX). That is most likely too much, unless you're on a fast connection using the fastest computers with a lot of ram.

For those contemplating this issue on their own sites, keep in mind that more and more mobile devices are accessing these sites, and the javascript on such devices just can't handle nearly as many points. My own site broke with the latest release of iOS6, and now I have to accommodate by changing my js to an easier system load.

But to get back to the answer at hand, what you'll have to do is make a new ajax call whenever the map bounds change, and if the zoom goes too far out, you'll have to limit the number retrieved and implement some system to show the user that not all results are shown. My site uses a limit of 250, if I recall correctly, and shows a bounding rectangle around the locations (along with markerclusterer to cluster them). Before populating with real data, I did a test database of thousands and thousands, and this number seemed to be the best tradeoff of performance and information. (But that was before I went mobile and before v3 of the api). v3 is supposed to be more streamlined, but mobile devices are limited, so you'll have to test.

Answer (score 0):

I am using marker clusterer plus library with a marker size cap of 200 and default zoom level 8. On zoom change or drag, another 200 markers will come on the map.

If you zoom-out the markers will be clustered and vice-versa.

Comment: Do you have a link to this library by any chance?